# SQL Server: composite key primary key constraint fk, can't understand a SQL schema diagram

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, foreign-keys, primary-key, composite-primary-key

I was looking for a basic SQL diagram for an e-commerce site and I came across this example: http://addons.oscommerce.com/info/3853/page,23.

There are a lots of tables with composite primary keys but they seem to be constraint with just one foreign key.

This is a capture of one the tables in subject:

`products_options_values_to_products_options` and `products_options_values`
schema: http://sdrv.ms/1bIMx52 (compositkey.jpg).

I was trying to constrain the columns `products_options_values_id` with `products_options_values_id`

I'm using SQL Server 2012, and I've tried to constrain the composite keys with one fk, clearly SQL Server Management Studio gave me an error, stating:

> The columns in table 'products_options_values(products)' do not match an existing primary key or UNIQUE constraint.

or

> Both sides of a relationship must have the same number of columns

I obviously agree with the 2 statements, but how come in the diagram the constraint seems possible?

I'd like to replicate the whole database scheme but I would like to understand this point first.

Luther

edit: as pointed out by Allan S. Hansen, I've applied an "unique key" to the primary key and despite what I knew, it's working.

This is a snippet of the mssql diagram:
[image]

Comment: I'd tentatively think you're right and the diagram is incorrect. Any chance that you can context the diagram's author?

Comment: That sample diagram is crap - or not suitable for SQL Server. In SQL Server, if you have a **composite primary key**, then **all** referencing foreign keys must also include **all columns** in the primary key they're referencing. This is not the case in that sample diagram.

Comment: Well, no - we need to seperate the concepts of PK and Unique Indexes. The requirement is that there must be a unique index over the columns from the composite key taking part in the FK. For example, I can make a table having *One, Two, Three* as a PK, but also making a unique index over *One, Three* - and then I can use just *One, Three* as a composite FK and omit *Two*. Granted, I can't think of many situations where that's applicable, but I've not given it much thought either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In context to my comment; this is completely possible in SQL Server:

[image: Composite FK without all composite PK]

As long as there's a unique index on column One, Three, then they those two together can be used as FK.

Where to use such a pattern, I'm not sure - because if PK_One can be defined by just One, Three, then I wouldn't think Two should be in that key, but well .... I've not given it much thought and I'm sure something can be thought up.

That's also why you received the error message:

> The columns in table 'products_options_values(products)' do not match
>   an existing primary key or UNIQUE constraint.

Remember, Primary Keys and Unique indexes aren't the same.

Comment: I've just applied, like in your diagram, an "unique key" on the "primary key" and it's working, foreign keys can now reference to it, thanks. Still I'm not sure if this is the best way to deal with table reference, it seems prone to errors and I can't see a major advantage. Do you think a surrogate primary key is the most simple option?

Comment: It's difficult to say, because as mentioned, I've not really given much thought to such a set-up so I don't particularly see much benefit in this specific pattern. When having a 'large composite key', I'd say it's often much more useful to make a surrogate key Primary Key, but then consider careful how to structure indexes (clustered and non-clustered). But basically - PK design is a very subjective technique, but my own approach is to look at the data and how it's going to be used, more than just doing what "the books says". Real life situations often differ from textbooks, so I'm pragmatic.